# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle-xuggler in java.library.path

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, xuggle, xuggler

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and Eclipse. I installed Xuggler succesfully, I've checked the environment variables and everything related with linux in their FAQ: http://wiki.xuggle.comFrequently_Asked_Questions#What.27s_up_with_java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.3F

I also set up Eclipse according to their tutorial:
http://xuggle.wordpress.com/2009/01/23/how-to-write-your-first-xuggler-application-in-eclipse/

Whenever I try running any code which uses Xuggler I get the following error:

```
2011-09-14 14:17:30,093 [main] ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle-xuggler; version: 3; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle-xuggler in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:265)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:168)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.<clinit>(IContainer.java:1457)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.<init>(MediaReader.java:137)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeReader(ToolFactory.java:77)
    at recode.main(recode.java:16)
```

So, how to solve this?

Comment: What is your java command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer/solution from the xuggler-users google group, credits to Navin Bhutada:

```
solve it by including the Xuggle variables before runing the netbeans like this:
export XUGGLE_HOME=/home/xyzuser/xuggler 
export PATH=$XUGGLE_HOME/lib:$XUGGLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$XUGGLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/bin/./netbeans"
```

I use eclipse, so I just changed that last line, running eclipse from its folder through the command line and everything worked just fine.

Note: If I export the variables and try opening eclipse from a shortcut on my desktop it doesn't work. The shortcut point to the same file I ran from the command line

TLDR:
export variables you got after installing
run Eclipse from the terminal.

Comment: So in the end, your environment variables weren't set up correctly after all? =)

Comment: Kind of. Opening eclipse through the desktop link would erase them, it seems.

Answer (score 3):

You just download correct Xuggle from this page based on ur os:
http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.2/
And then extract the lib files to project home folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that even though I may have my environment variables set correctly, explicitly including the Xuggler install dir in the java.library.path when executing saves me from that problem.

i.e. `java -Djava.library.path="$XUGGLE_HOME" myExecutable`

Answer (score 0):

Cause Could be un-availability of dependency jars or version conflicts.

Adding the following jars in the classpath worked fine for me:

xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
logback-core-1.0.0.jar
logback-classic-1.0.0.jar

Note: Add them in the library folder using "Add jar/Folder" Option in netbeans.