# Error while creating Image Frames from Video in Java

Tags: java

I want to capture images from video using xuggle. Add xuggle-xuggler-3.0.660.jar in lib folder. It gives the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.<clinit>(JNILibraryLoader.java:47)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.Global.<clinit>(Global.java:240)
    at testing.VideoThumbnailsExample.<clinit>(VideoThumbnailsExample.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 4 more
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

I wrote the following code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testing;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaListenerAdapter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.event.IVideoPictureEvent;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;

public class VideoThumbnailsExample {
    public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 10;
    private static final String inputFilename = "D:/bailey.mpg";
    private static final String outputFilePrefix = "c:/photo/a/mysnapshot";
    // The video stream index, used to ensure we display frames from one and
    // only one video stream from the media container.
    private static int mVideoStreamIndex = -1;
    // Time of last frame write
    private static long mLastPtsWrite = Global.NO_PTS;
    public static final long MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = (long)(Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);
        // stipulate that we want BufferedImages created in BGR 24bit color space
        mediaReader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        mediaReader.addListener(new ImageSnapListener());
        // read out the contents of the media file and
        // dispatch events to the attached listener
        while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) ;
    }

    private static class ImageSnapListener extends MediaListenerAdapter {
        public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {
            if (event.getStreamIndex() != mVideoStreamIndex) {
                // if the selected video stream id is not yet set, go ahead an
                // select this lucky video stream
                if (mVideoStreamIndex == -1)
                    mVideoStreamIndex = event.getStreamIndex();
               else // no need to show frames from this video stream
                 return;
           }

           // if uninitialized, back date mLastPtsWrite to get the very first frame
           if (mLastPtsWrite == Global.NO_PTS)
                mLastPtsWrite = event.getTimeStamp() - MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
            // if it's time to write the next frame
            if (event.getTimeStamp() - mLastPtsWrite >= MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES) {
                String outputFilename = dumpImageToFile(event.getImage());
                // indicate file written
                double seconds = ((double) event.getTimeStamp()) / Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND;
                System.out.printf("at elapsed time of %6.3f seconds wrote: %s\n", seconds, outputFilename);
                // update last write time
                mLastPtsWrite += MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
            }
        }

        private String dumpImageToFile(BufferedImage image) {
           try {
                String outputFilename = outputFilePrefix + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(outputFilename));
                return outputFilename;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory` you must include sl4j jar file into your project build path,you can download it from [here](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html)

Comment: jenuine I have add slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar and slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar in build path.but now it gives following Error

Comment: [main] ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle-xuggler; version: 3; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.Global_NO_PTS_get()J
 at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.Global_NO_PTS_get(Native Method)
 at com.xuggle.xuggler.Global.<clinit>(Global.java:240)
 at testing.VideoThumbnailsExample.<clinit>(

Comment: Could not load library: xuggle-xuggler :i think problem with that lib,did u add all dependant libraries

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420771/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-xuggle-xuggler-in-java-library-path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324478/how-do-i-have-to-install-configure-xuggle-to-not-get-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: jenuine Actually i add  xuggle-xuggler-3.0.660.jar library in my build path and can u post liks for slf4j-1.6.6 jar.because i am getting others except it..