# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path

Tags: java, linux, media

I have write a program which basically crop an image form video. To do this i have used xuggle-xuggler-5.4 jar file. Now when i run this program on my local machine it works fine. But after deployment on server which is linux based server. It give me an error. I do not how to resolved it. Locally i run this program on window env and server is linux based. I also google for this problem where i found some class path problem. but class path is also perfectly fine.

can some body tell me how can i over come form this problem.

```
type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:268)
    com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:171)
    com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.load(JNILibrary.java:161)
    com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:16)
    com.xuggle.ferry.Ferry.<clinit>(Ferry.java:25)
    com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
    com.xuggle.xuggler.Global.<clinit>(Global.java:238)
    com.test.ImageFrameFromVideo.<clinit>(ImageFrameFromVideo.java:37)
    com.server.servlet.UploadVideoServlet.saveVideo(UploadVideoServlet.java:127)
    com.server.servlet.UploadVideoServlet.doPost(UploadVideoServlet.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 logs.`enter code here`
```

Comment: Have you tried this?

It shows how to resolve this error on linux.
[StackOverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420771/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-xuggle-xuggler-in-java-library-path

Comment: Dear Pankaj, It did not helped me a lot. Its my first time to deploy an application on server. So i do not know how to set path variable of server.

Comment: You mean to say how to set environment variables for linux?

Comment: I really do not know . what to do to solve this  problem.

Comment: I really do not know . what to do to solve this  problem. My problem is this app is working fine in local machine which is window based system. but when i deployed this app on server then i got the given error which is linux based system. To find the solution of this problem i google but still blocked.